# Avoid line breaks in a div

Tags: php, html, css

How can I avoid line breaks in a div when I use a php funcion. My code is HTML is

```
<div class="toolbar"> 
  <div style="float:left; "> 
    Profile <?php get_search_form(); ?> 
  </div>
</div>
```

and my code in css is

```
.toolbar {
  background: #F2F2D7;
  width: inherit;
  font-family: "Palatino";
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px 2px #888888;
  z-index:2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

with that I obtain something like:

```
<p> Profile </p> <p> Buscador </p>
<p> and what I want is </p>
```

Profile Buscador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what `get_search_form()` is returning.  If it is returning a string, then you may need to look at the applied styling for the containing `div`.

If it is returning an an HTML fragment (e.g., <span>your result</span>), you may need to adjust the results to not include any embbed `div` tags.

Comment: how can i adjust the result if it is a predefined function, something similar happens with <?php wp_register(); ?>, it always include div tags

Comment: You may have to use string manipulation to remove/replace the tags you don't want included in your results.  It is possible to style for a specific location to correct these issues without changing the markup, but that would make your CSS horribly bloated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your looking for the `<span>` tag. Its used to divide segments of HTML for styling.

Comment: How are you using it? How exactly is it not working? Not allowing style, or breaking the text? You need to use it like so <span class="stylesheet"> example plaintext </span>

Comment: breaking the text, it results exactly the same

Comment: Okay. Check weather its a php problem or html. Replace the php with html filler and see if it breaks. If not, it's definitely a php problem.

Comment: it works with html, so it's a php problem, but I don't know how to fix it. it's a litle frustrating because there is no informartion about it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as user197092 said, this is a php problem, and if it is a predifined function it could be hard to adjust the result to not include embbed div tags. I solved it using flex, my code is:

```
<div id="toolbar"> 

            <div id="toolbar1"> 
                Profile
            </div>

            <div id="toolbar2"> 
                <?php echo get_search_form(); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
```

and for CSS

```
#toolbar {
display: flex;}

#toolbar1 {
flex: 1;}

#toolbar2 {
flex: 2;
margin-left: 10px; }
```

this worked for me